# Trigonometric identity for $\sin 6x$

Tags: trigonometry

I got this question from my teacher:

> $\sin {6x}=\dots$

Try to make this one from this: $\sin(3x+3x)$, then according to the formula ended up like this:

$$2\sin{(2x+x)}\cos{(2x+x)}$$
$$2((\sin(2x)\cos(x)+\cos(2x)\sin(x))\cdot(\cos(2x)\cos(x)+\sin(2x)\sin(x)))$$

Then I just have no idea how to continue. Should I use the formula again or what?

Comment: Have you learned [DeMoivre's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre's_formula) yet? If not, then you can still use $\cos 2x = 2\cos^2 x - 1$ and $\sin 2x = 2\sin x \cos x$.

Comment: alright let me try it for a miniute, please don't leave this post yet,

Answer (score 4):

Since you are willing to learn [DeMoivre's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre's_formula), I'll use it.

For any $n$, we have $\cos nx + i\sin nx = (\cos x + i\sin x)^n$.

Now, lets set $n = 6$ and use the Binomial theorem:

$\cos 6x + i\sin 6x = (\cos x + i\sin x)^6 = \displaystyle\sum_{k = 0}^{6}\dbinom{6}{k}(\cos x)^k(i\sin x)^{6-k}$

If we write out all the terms, and use the fact that $i^2 = -1$, $i^3 = -i$, and $i^4 = 1$, we get:

$\cos 6x + i\sin 6x = \cos^6 x + 6i\cos^5 x\sin x - 15\cos^4 x \sin^2 x - 20i\cos^3 x\sin^3 x + 15\cos^2 x\sin^4 x +6i\cos x\sin^5 x - \sin^6 x$

Now, set the real parts and imaginary parts equal:

$\cos 6x = \cos^6 x - 15\cos^4 x \sin^2 x + 15\cos^2 x\sin^4 x - \sin^6 x$

$\sin 6x = 6\cos^5 x\sin x - 20\cos^3 x\sin^3 x +6\cos x\sin^5 x$

As you can see, this gets us both the identities for $\cos 6x$ and $\sin 6x$ simultaneously, but it does require you to know a bit about complex numbers, and the binomial theorem.

If you don't know these, you can continue what you have already done by using the following:

$\sin 2x = \sin(x+x) = \sin x \cos x + \cos x \sin x = 2\sin x \cos x$

$\cos 2x = \cos(x+x) = \cos x \cos x - \sin x \sin x = \cos^2 x - \sin^2 x$

Comment: i still confuse with DeMoivre's formula, but i think gonna learn that for this couple of days, but for now gonna continue with use normal formula :-)

Comment: It's probably less confusing if you first see $\sin 2x$ and $\cos 2x$ derived by expanding $\cos 2x + i\sin 2x$ $= (\cos x + i\sin x)^2$ $= \cos^2 x + 2i\cos x \sin x + i^2 \sin^2 x$ $= (\cos^2 x - \sin^2 x) + i(2\sin x \cos x)$. Regardless, use the formulas that you are comfortable with for now. You'll probably better understand DeMoivre's Theorem when you learn it in class.

Comment: yeahh, i'm agree with you :-)

Comment: hey, i'm still not done yet, and ended up in this one
$2sin x((\cos^2 x - sin^2 x + 2cos^2 x)(\cos^3 x - \sin^2 x - 2sin^2 xcos x))$ then what shoul i do ?

Answer (score 3):

You can manipulate with those two formulas
$$\sin(x+y)=\sin(x)\cos(y)+\cos(x)\sin(y)$$
$$\cos(x+y)=\cos(x)\cos(y)-\sin(x)\sin(y)$$
for example
$$\sin(6x)=\sin(3x+3x)=\sin(2\cdot3x)=2\sin(3x)\cos(3x)$$
$$\sin(3x)=\sin(x+2x)=\sin(x)\cos(2x)+\sin(2x)\cos(x)$$
$$\cos(3x)=\cos(x+2x)=\cos(x)\cos(2x)-\sin(2x)\sin(x)$$
$$\sin(2x)=\sin(x+x)=\sin(x)\cos(x)+\sin(x)\cos(x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$$
$$\cos(2x)=\cos(x+x)=\cos(x)\cos(x)-\sin(x)\sin(x)=\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)$$

Comment: i done until this part $2((2sin{x}cos^2{2x})+(2cos^2{2x}sin{x}-sin{x})(2cos^2{x}cos{x}-cos{x}-2sin^2{x}cos{x}))$ then what should i do next ? am i right or wrong ?

Comment: Presumably it's this bit you need $\cos^22x= \left(2\cos^2x -1\right)^2$ But depends on what you are trying to achieve? Still not clear from your question :/